# Mongodb Aggregation to count element pairs and individual elements

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have following data:

```
{ "id" : 1, "lsPairs" :[{"location" : "L0", "service" : "S0" }]}
{ "id" : 2, "lsPairs" :[{"location" : "L0", "service" : "S0" },{"location" : "L1", "service" : "S1"}]}
{ "id" : 3, "lsPairs" :[{"location" : "L0", "service" : "S0" },{"location" : "L1", "service" : "S1"},                    {"location" : "L2", "service" : "S2"}]}
{ "id" : 4, "lsPairs" :[{"location" : "L0", "service" : "S0" },{"location" : "L1", "service" : "S1"},{"location" : "L2", "service" : "S2"}, {"location" : "L3", "service" : "S3"}]}`
```

I want to get location count, service count and (location,service) pair count

```
{ "_id" : "L3" , "count" : 1}
{ "_id" : "L2" , "count" : 2}
{ "_id" : "L1" , "count" : 3}
{ "_id" : "L0" , "count" : 4}

{ "_id" : "S3" , "count" : 1}
{ "_id" : "S2" , "count" : 2}
{ "_id" : "S1" , "count" : 3}
{ "_id" : "S0" , "count" : 4}

{ "_id" : { "loc" : "L2" , "srv" : "S2"} , "count" : 2}
{ "_id" : { "loc" : "L1" , "srv" : "S1"} , "count" : 3}
{ "_id" : { "loc" : "L3" , "srv" : "S3"} , "count" : 1}
{ "_id" : { "loc" : "L0" , "srv" : "S0"} , "count" : 4}`
```

Now I run group function three times, group different id.
Any idea for using one group to get these result?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to deconstruct the array with `$unwind` then `$group` the documents.

```
collection.aggregate([
    { $unwind: "$lsPairs" },
    { $group: { 
        _id: { 
            "loc": "$lsPairs.location", 
            "srv": "$lsPairs.service"
        }, 
        "count": { $sum: 1 }
    }}
])
```

Output

```
{ "_id" : { "loc" : "L3", "srv" : "S3" }, "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : { "loc" : "L2", "srv" : "S2" }, "count" : 2 }
{ "_id" : { "loc" : "L1", "srv" : "S1" }, "count" : 3 }
{ "_id" : { "loc" : "L0", "srv" : "S0" }, "count" : 4 }
```

Comment: ya, but I also want to get loc count and srv count separately.

Comment: FWIK a single query cannot return all three documents separately

Comment: I know it is difficult, I have used three query to get the result, and I just want to know have any idea using one aggregation query to get the all result. Anyway, thanks styvane.

Answer (score 0):

The following I add location and service to array, can I group two array same time

```
db.locservice.aggregate([ {$unwind:"$lsPairs"}, 
                          {$group:{_id:"$lsPairs",count: { $sum: 1}, 
                                   locs:{$push:{item:"$lsPairs.location"}}, 
                                   srvs:{$push:{item:"$lsPairs.service"}}}}, 
                          {$project:{count:1, locs:1, srvs:1}} ])

{ "_id" : { "location" : "L3", "service" : "S3" }, "count" : 1, "locs" : [ { "item" : "L3" } ], "srvs"  : [ { "item" : "S3" } ] }
{ "_id" : { "location" : "L2", "service" : "S2" }, "count" : 2, "locs" : [ { "item" : "L2" }, { "item" : "L2" } ], "srvs" : [ { "item" : "S2" }, { "item" : "S2" } ] }
{ "_id" : { "location" : "L1", "service" : "S1" }, "count" : 3, "locs" : [ { "item" : "L1" }, { "item" : "L1" }, { "item" : "L1" } ], "srvs" : [ { "item" : "S1" }, { "item" : "S1" }, { "item" : "S1" } ] }
{ "_id" : { "location" : "L0", "service" : "S0" }, "count" : 4, "locs" : [ { "item" : "L0" }, { "item" : "L0" }, { "item" : "L0" }, { "item" : "L0" } ], "srvs" : [ { "item" : "S0" }, { "item" : "S0" }, { "item" : "S0" }, { "item" : "S0" } ] }
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep the first round location-service pair to a collection and reused it.

```
db.locservice.aggregate([ {$unwind:"$lsPairs"}, 
                          {$group:{_id:"$lsPairs",count: { $sum: 1}}},  
                          {$sort:{_id:1}}, 
                          {$out:"lsp"} ])
```

Take location from temp collection and group it.

```
db.lsp.aggregate([{$project:{_id:0, loc:"$_id.location", count:1}}, 
                  {$group:{_id:"$loc", cnt:{$sum:"$count"}}},  {$sort:{_id:1}} ])
```

Take service from temp collection and group it.

```
db.lsp.aggregate([{$project:{_id:0, srv:"$_id.service", count:1}}, 
                  {$group:{_id:"$srv", cnt:{$sum:"$count"}}},  {$sort:{_id:1}} ])
```